# How to use all the Unix environment variables?

Tags: java, unix, environment-variables, jsch

Using Java (JSch API) I am trying to execute an Unix command on a remote machine. Now, to successfully execute this command I need to use all the environment variables already set on the remote box.

I can use `export <variable>` command to set the variables on runtime. But as the number of such variables is quite large I am wondering if there is any better way to use the variables in runtime.

Can anyone help please or should I explain a bit more?

Comment: Are these variables ones that are normally present when you log in via ssh and execute your command manually?

Comment: @harmic yes you are correct, these are by default available when I run command via console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save variables into a file:

```
set > /tmp/vars
echo "A=120" >> /tmp/vars
```

and then "import" the variables with dot in a script like this:

```
set -a
. /tmp/vars
mycommand
```

Comment: I think that is a good solution. Just instead of `set` I need to use `printenv`.

Answer (score 1):

The work around I found was to use

```
set | mycommand
```

Set will manually call the initialization process and it will add environment variables into the scope.

JSch calls bash with -c. This causes .bashrc not to be initialized inside of the bash scope. Set will read the .bashrc file and other config files.